# ImageButton drag out after click

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` (Save) which is drag in with finger.

I want after I click on it to drag out automatically (now I have to click on the screen , to have the ImgBtn drag out)

[image]

This is how I declared the button in xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

    <!-- this is my image button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_width="130dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've see the only way is to use animation and OnClick programmaticaly start animation with "android:fillAfter" as true.

If I understand you correct and "drag out" mean slide out off the screen.

slideOut.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
         android:fromXDelta="0%"
         android:toXDelta="100%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%"
         android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

In layout

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="SlideOut" />
```

In code

```
function SlideOut() {
    findViewById(R.id.imageButton).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideOut));
}
```

Comment: can you be more explicit, please ?